# Cholesky decomposition and confidence ellipsoid

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, matrix, covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to construct an error ellipsoid from a covariance matrix (which exists for a 3D point) and then sample consistent xyz points in this region. (This question succeeds [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102704/3277) one.)

What I'm currently doing is:

1) Calculate the Cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix.
2) Sample each initial vertex point as a Gaussian with width 1 to generate (x', y', z')
3) Multiply (x',y',z') by the Cholesky decomposition matrix for the newly generated point.
4) Add this result to a matrix of the mean values.

To add some more concrete details, the covariance matrix of the initial point is:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
  10.0115     & -10.6835 & 5.18024 \\
  -10.6835 & 11.4009 & -5.52798 \\
  5.18024 & -5.52798 & 2.77646 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

I then calculate the Cholesky decomposition, which is:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
3.164095& 0& 0\\
-3.376478& 0.017131& 0\\
1.637195& -0.001619& 0.309921\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

And the initial xyz point is at (35.5361, -37.2661, 22.521).

Generating three random numbers from a Gaussian of mean 0 and width 1 yielded:
-0.377495, -0.933623, 0.241011, and at this point I'm not completely clear on the correct procedure.

My assumption is that it is correct to multiply the Cholesky decomposition matrix by a matrix containing the randomly generated Gaussian points, and then add this to a matrix containing the initial values. This would look like this:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
35.5361& 0& 0\\
0& -37.2661& 0\\
0& 0& 22.521\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix} 
3.164095& 0& 0\\
-3.376478& 0.017131& 0\\
1.637195& -0.001619& 0.309921\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
-0.377495& 0& 0\\
0 & -0.933623 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.241011\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

For which the result is:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
34.3417�& 0& 0\\
0 & -37.281 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 22.5957\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

And I could definitely believe that a new xyz point at (34.3417,-37.281,22.5957) could be consistent with what I want to generate, but I'm still not completely confident I have followed a valid procedure to generate this.

Any comments would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can't understand how what you are doing crosses with your question title. Multiplying orthonormal data by Cholesky root of a covariance matrix makes the data covariate right according that cov matrix. And if the data is a random sample from orthonormal population, then the same trick yields data which is a random sample from population with the cov matrix. But sorry, I can't trace, how it connects to drawing an ellips.

Comment: I was trying to follow something similar to the procedure described [here](http://jellymatter.com/2011/03/31/drawing-confidence-ellipses-and-ellipsoids/), where you use the Cholesky decomposition to calculate points on an ellipse corresponding to a covariance matrix. Have I got this horribly wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is useful to add that my concern is the off-diagonals of the Cholesky matrix don't have an effect on the final result. I can't see whether or not this is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial point and the sample should be vectors, not matrices.  So you should get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
35.5361\\
-37.2661\\
22.521\\
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 
3.164095& 0& 0\\
-3.376478& 0.017131& 0\\
1.637195& -0.001619& 0.309921\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
-0.377495\\
-0.933623 \\
0.241011\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
34.3417\\
-37.281 \\
22.5957\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But other than that, yes, your procedure is correct.